# Replace changed values in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using the following macro to compare changes from week to week between 2 spreadsheets and it dumps the changes to a 3rd sheet. However it dumps the original row and then another row with the changed value only and highlights both values. How can I get it to just dump 1 row with the changed value? I don't need two rows or the original and changed values shown, just need 1 row with the complete new changed value.

```
Option Explicit
Dim miMaxColumns As Integer
Sub CompareSheets()
Dim bChanged As Boolean, baChanged() As Boolean
Dim iColEnd As Integer, iCol As Integer, iCol1 As Integer, iCol2 As Integer
Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long, lReportRow As Long
Dim objDictOld As Object, objDictNew As Object
Dim vKeys As Variant, vKey As Variant
Dim vaInput() As Variant, vaOutput() As Variant, vaOutput2() As Variant
Dim vaInputOld As Variant, vaInputNew As Variant
Dim wsOld As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, wsReport As Worksheet


Set wsOld = Sheets("Sheet1")
miMaxColumns = wsOld.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set objDictOld = PopulateDictionary(WS:=wsOld)
Set wsNew = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set objDictNew = PopulateDictionary(WS:=wsNew)

Set wsReport = Sheets("Sheet3")

With wsReport
    .Cells.ClearFormats
    .Cells.ClearContents
End With

wsOld.Range("A1:" & wsOld.Cells(1, miMaxColumns).Address).Copy
wsReport.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

lReportRow = 1
vKeys = objDictOld.Keys
For Each vKey In vKeys
    ReDim vaInputOld(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns)
    vaInputOld = objDictOld.Item(vKey)
    If objDictNew.exists(vKey) Then
        ReDim vaInputNew(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns)
        vaInputNew = objDictNew.Item(vKey)
        ReDim vaOutput(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns + 1)
        ReDim vaOutput2(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns + 1)
        ReDim baChanged(1 To miMaxColumns)
        bChanged = False
        For iCol = 1 To miMaxColumns
            vaOutput(1, iCol + 1) = vaInputOld(1, iCol)
            If vaInputOld(1, iCol) <> vaInputNew(1, iCol) Then
                vaOutput2(1, iCol + 1) = vaInputNew(1, iCol)
                baChanged(iCol) = True
                bChanged = True
            End If
        Next iCol
        If bChanged Then
            lReportRow = lReportRow + 1
            For iCol = 1 To UBound(baChanged)
                If baChanged(iCol) Then
                    With wsReport
                        .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, iCol + 1).Address, _
                               .Cells(lReportRow + 1, iCol + 1).Address).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End With
                End If
            Next iCol

            vaOutput(1, 1) = "Changed"
            With wsReport
                .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 1).Address, _
                       .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput
                lReportRow = lReportRow + 1
                .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 1).Address, _
                       .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput2
            End With
        End If
        objDictOld.Remove vKey
        objDictNew.Remove vKey
    Else
        ReDim vaOutput(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns + 1)
        vaOutput(1, 1) = "Deleted"
        For iCol = 1 To miMaxColumns
            vaOutput(1, iCol + 1) = vaInputOld(1, iCol)
        Next iCol

        lReportRow = lReportRow + 1
        With wsReport
            .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 1).Address, .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput
            '-- Set the row to light grey
            .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 2).Address, .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End With
    End If
Next vKey

If objDictNew.Count <> 0 Then
    vKeys = objDictNew.Keys
    For Each vKey In vKeys
        ReDim vaOutput2(1 To 1, 1 To miMaxColumns + 1)
        vaInputNew = objDictNew.Item(vKey)
        vaOutput2(1, 1) = "Inserted"
        For iCol = 1 To miMaxColumns
            vaOutput2(1, iCol + 1) = vaInputNew(1, iCol)
        Next iCol
        lReportRow = lReportRow + 1
        With wsReport
            .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 1).Address, .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput2
            '-- Set the row to light green
            .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 2).Address, .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End With
    Next vKey
End If

objDictOld.RemoveAll
Set objDictOld = Nothing
objDictNew.RemoveAll
Set objDictNew = Nothing
End Sub
Private Function PopulateDictionary(ByRef WS As Worksheet) As Object
Dim lRowEnd As Long, lRow As Long
Dim rCur As Range
Dim sKey As String

Set PopulateDictionary = Nothing
Set PopulateDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lRowEnd = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For lRow = 2 To lRowEnd
    sKey = Trim$(LCase$(CStr(WS.Range("A" & lRow).Value)))
    On Error Resume Next
    PopulateDictionary.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=WS.Range(WS.Cells(lRow, 1).Address, _
                                            WS.Cells(lRow, miMaxColumns).Address).Value
    On Error GoTo 0
Next lRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the "old" values are pasted:

```
wsReport.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

So just comment that out.

If you change the IF bChanged THEN statement to:

```
    If bChanged Then
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(baChanged)
            If baChanged(iCol) Then
                With wsReport
                    .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, iCol + 1).Address, _
                           .Cells(lReportRow, iCol + 1).Address).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End With
            End If
        Next iCol

        vaOutput(1, 1) = "Changed"
        With wsReport
            .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, 1).Address, _
                   .Cells(lReportRow, miMaxColumns + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput

            For iCol = 1 To UBound(baChanged)
                If baChanged(iCol) Then
                    With wsReport
                        .Range(.Cells(lReportRow, iCol + 1).Address, _
                               .Cells(lReportRow, iCol + 1).Address).Value = vaOutput2(1, iCol + 1)
                    End With
                End If
            Next iCol
        End With
        lReportRow = lReportRow + 1
    End If
```

...it should all be in one line.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was struggling getting it to merge the line!

Only one small change request if possible. It's still creating the 2nd row, only blank now and with the highlight of where the change would be. How would I eliminate that 2nd row and just have the 1 row with the merged, highlighted change?

Comment: I have edited my reply; I have just removed the first lReportRow = lReportRow + 1... That should do the trick.

Comment: If that solves the problem, could you please accept the answer to close the topic.

Comment: Yes that did it!! I also had to move the "lReportRow = lReportRow + 1" outside the "End With" in the light grey and light green section as it was putting a blank row inbetween the section you fixed and the other sections. All is perfect now! Thank you!!!